# unable to use Zend_Registry

Tags: zend-framework, registry

I'm new in ZendFramework and need help..
I'm facing problem regarding Zend_Registry.
I have an AuthController in which I login functionality handled and set person type in Zend_Registry

```
$reg = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$reg['personType'] = $str['person_type'];
```

when i get value inside AuthController it works fine

```
$reg = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$userType = $reg['personType'];
```

I have also PersonController in which I am dealing with change password functionality in which I need personType also but when i do

```
$reg = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$userType = $reg['personType'];
```

This returns NULL to $userType but i need personType here. 
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Use Zend_Registry as it should.

To write to registry: `Zend_Registry::set('personType', $str['person_type']);`

To read from registry: `Zend_Registry::get('personType');`

**EDIT**: OK i checked your way and it seems to be working too. Never seen it before.

So back to your problem. I think your AuthController and your PersonController are not called within this same PHP instance. Zend Registry stores data only from time when user requests page till page is sent to user. When you set it during login it will NOT have this data on subsequent user requests.
You need to use session for that.

Comment: I had also tried the method you mentioned.
thanks , i appreciate that i have to use Session

Answer (score 0):

Actually zend registry will keep the data for the next request only. you will have to use zend session instead of zend registry